# Google Cloud Print cannot convert to PDF

Tags: php, google-cloud-print

I have a setup at my workplace where we receiver orders, and I print them to four different printers at the most relevant location. I am using the Google Cloud Print API to do this.

However I face problems when printing a bigger amount (100+ documents within an hour). I get a non descript error with code 403 and errormessage `Could not convert to PDF`.

I am using PHP to interact with the API. I am using synchronous request, and am sending html data.
I have tried adding a small delay (5 seconds) between each API call, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. That is not feasible either though, as we need a large print volume.

I am hoping someone has had similar issues, and found a solution.

Comment: The problem seems to have fixed itself @usama . I have not really changed anything, but haven't seen this issue for the last couple of months.

Comment: Note to this. Google cloud print api will be deprecated by jan 2021. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006